# require error in ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm working on a Ruby gem and I'm getting an odd error. I have previously released this gem without too much trouble. I added some methods / refactored some code and wanted to release a subsequent version (from 1.1 to 1.2).

For reference, the name of the gem is *Intervallum*, (the word 'interval' in Latin).

I'm getting a 'require' error that's been stumping me.

The folder tree is:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── intervallum-[version].gem
├── intervallum.gemspec
└── lib
    ├── intervallum
    │   ├── module.scroll.rb
    │   └── module.spell.rb
    └── intervallum.rb
```

In `lib/intervallum.rb` I tried `Dir.glob`, `Dir['./lib/intervallum/*']` and `require '../intervallum/lib/intervallum/module.spell.rb'` and what happens for each one is:

Locally, after `gem build intervallum.gemspec` and `gem install intervallum-[version].gem`, I boot up `irb` and `require intervallum` and it works fine.

- push to RubyGems
- remove the local copy
- install from RG
- load up in irb I get load errors or it cannot find class of a helper class

I'm not sure why this keeps occurring, or if there's something that I'm missing as to why this keeps occurring but any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not including those files in the gem when it gets packaged. Your gemspec specifies that only the `lib/intervallum.rb` file will be included in the gem:

```
s.files   = ["./lib/intervallum.rb"]
```

Change that line to include all files in lib.  It's also a good idea to include the gemspec.

```
s.files = Dir['lib/**/*', 'intervallum.gemspec']
```

Comment: Got to work this morning... figured out the exact same thing... thank you